# How does GCC detect processor features

Tags: gcc, optimization, clang

Using the gcc flag -march=native enables CPU specific optimizations for the cpu gcc is being run on. (correct me if I am wrong). How does gcc detect these features? Extra points for links to the code, and comparison to clang/llvm also.

More practically, how can I detect cpu features on a machine (with no gcc, or an extremely old gcc), and then compile for that machine on my local machine. IE a gcc -march=that_other_pc. (hopefully easier than compiling gcc for that architecture and running it there).

Comment: If that is true how does enabling -march=native improve performance? Surely then the required first step would be to recompile gcc, enabling autoconf to detect your system. If you are correct can you provide a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gcc, in fact, does have a cpu capabilities detection routine. If the spec for the current build contains a `%:local_cpu_detect(args)` construct, the driver for the arch in question will invoke a `host_detect_local_cpu` driver function which will try to query the current system CPU and to obtain the desired capability flags from it.

On `i386` and derived arches the process looks roughly like this:
https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc/blob/da8dff89fa9398f04b107e388cb706517ced9505/gcc/config/i386/driver-i386.c#L383

(In short, the function invokes the `cpuid` opcode as required and then parses the returned capability regs).